# data.table is not handling integer64 in by statement

Tags: r, data.table

Using `fread` from data.table load `integer64` correctly, though I have the impression that `by` statements are not handling int64 correctly.
I am probably doing someting wrong here, what is it ?

```
library(data.table); library(bit64);
test = data.table(x=c(1,2,3),y=c('x','q','q'),ID=as.integer64(c('432706205348805058','432706205348805058','432706205348805059')))

str(test) #the display is wrong (BUT IT IS EXPECTED)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x : num  1 2 3
# $ y : chr  "x" "q" "q"
# $ ID:Class 'integer64'  num [1:3] 9.52e-280 9.52e-280 9.52e-280
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

test # Here it is displayed correctly
#   x y                 ID
#1: 1 x 432706205348805058
#2: 2 q 432706205348805058
#3: 3 q 432706205348805059

txtR) test$ID
integer64
[1] 432706205348805058 432706205348805058 432706205348805059

txtR) test[,list(count=.N),by=ID] #WRRRONG
                   ID count
1: 432706205348805058     3
```

Comment: Related to https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=2552&group_id=240 ?

Comment: seems like it's losing precision while using `by`? `unique(as.numeric(ID))` gives only 1 value. But I wonder if it's the case because it returns back a "integer64" object (when using `by=ID`)

Comment: Yes I know that. But coercing to `as.numeric` doesn't. So I was wondering if the `by` is somehow losing precision.

Comment: not sure why it would cast to numeric... it seems that `integer64` inherits from `double` the vignette is 70 pages... I tried to go through but couldn't find anything

Comment: I'm not saying it does. Rather that I suspect it has something to do with precision while grouping.

Comment: I've tried a workaround using package `gmp` instead of `bit64`. This package stores integers as raw bytes. I just replaced `as.integer64` with `as.bigz`, and got this results: `test[,list(count=.N),by=ID]`: ` Error in '[.data.table'(test, , list(count = .N), by = ID) : column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type raw. Do not quote column names. Useage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update: This is now implemented in v1.9.3 (available from R-Forge), see [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> o  `bit64::integer64` now works in grouping and joins, #5369. Thanks to James Sams for highlighting UPCs and Clayton Stanley.
>        Reminder: `fread()` has been able to detect and read `integer64` for a while.

On OP's example above:

```
test[, .N, by=ID]
#                    ID N
# 1: 432706205348805058 2
# 2: 432706205348805059 1
```

---

`integer64` isn't yet implemented for `data.table` operations such as `setkey` or `by`. It was just implemented in `fread` only (first released to CRAN on 6 March 2013) as a first step. It could be useful as a value column for example.

I may have confused matters by filing a bug report relating to this (the one @Arun linked to). Strictly speaking, it isn't a bug but a feature request. I think of the bug list more like 'important things to resolve before the next release'.

Contributions are very welcome.