# Is it a bug in data.table and integer64 I found

Tags: r, integer, 64-bit, data.table

I am having a lot of difficulties with `data.table` and `integer64` (package `bit64`)> My understanding is that `integer64` cannot yet be used in a `by` clause. Though I might have found a bug in the "`sort`".

```
library(data.table)
library(bit64)

test4 <- structure(list(IDFD = c("360627720722618433", "360627720722618433"
), CDVCA = c("2013-03-13T09:36:07.795", "2013-03-13T09:36:07.795"
), NUMSEQ = structure(c(1.05397451390436e-309, 1.05397443975625e-309
), class = "integer64")), .Names = c("IDFD", "CDVCA", "NUMSEQ"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

str(test4)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ IDFD  : chr  "360627720722618433" "360627720722618433"
 $ CDVCA : chr  "2013-03-13T09:36:07.795" "2013-03-13T09:36:07.795"
 $ NUMSEQ:Class 'integer64'  num [1:2] 1.05e-309 1.05e-309

test4 <- as.data.table(test4)

str(test4)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ IDFD  : chr  "360627720722618433" "360627720722618433"
 $ CDVCA : chr  "2013-03-13T09:36:07.795" "2013-03-13T09:36:07.795"
 $ NUMSEQ:Class 'integer64'  num [1:2] 1.05e-309 1.05e-309
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

setkey(test4,IDFD,CDVCA,NUMSEQ)
test4
                 IDFD                   CDVCA          NUMSEQ
1: 360627720722618433 2013-03-13T09:36:07.795 213326816542720
2: 360627720722618433 2013-03-13T09:36:07.795 213326801534975 #THIS IS NOT SORTED !!
```

Am I right ?

Comment: Please be specifical what is the issue you're reporting? That `data.table::sort` and other operations don't support integer64? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614846/data-table-is-not-handling-integer64-in-by-statement. Are you using package versions data.table 1.8.11, bit64 0.9.3 or later?

Comment: dude I sent this 6 months ago...

Comment: Yes I know that. So please either clarify it, correct it or delete it.

Comment: I'm seeing similar weirdness and it helps to know what package versions this happens on.

Comment: statquant, could you verify this answer as well and close/accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update: This is now implemented in v1.9.3 (available from R-Forge), see [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> o  `bit64::integer64` now works in grouping and joins, #5369. Thanks to James Sams for highlighting UPCs and Clayton Stanley.
>        Reminder: `fread()` has been able to detect and read `integer64` for a while.

On OP's example above:

```
test4
#                  IDFD                   CDVCA          NUMSEQ
# 1: 360627720722618433 2013-03-13T09:36:07.795 213326801534975 ## sorted right
# 2: 360627720722618433 2013-03-13T09:36:07.795 213326816542720
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this, without changing the field value by doing a:

```
df[order(as.numeric(as.character(myint64field)), myotherfield),]
```

Obviously, you're gonna take a performance hit.