# integer64 class in r data.table, sum() and by=.()

Tags: r, data.table

I just noticed this issue with a column in a `data.table` that turned out to be of the integer64 class. I was reading the data using `fread` from a location on the internet and was not aware that the column in question was being interpreted as integer64, a class I am not familiar with. The issue is how this class behaves in a `data.table` when using `sum()` and `by`. It has been referenced similarly in two other questions on here, but that was in the context of using it as an ID value ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614846/data-table-is-not-handling-integer64-in-by-statement) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444036/is-it-a-bug-in-data-table-and-integer64-i-found?noredirect=1&lq=1))

When performing a `sum()` by group on this integer64 column, it does not behave as expected (as a numeric) *when there are negative values in the column*. Why is this? Is it a bug?

```
library(data.table); library(bit64)

z <- data.table(
  group = c("A","A","A"),
  int64 = as.integer64(c(10,20,-10)),
  numeric = c(10,20,-10)
)
```

To start, it works fine without the `by` statement:

```
z[, sum(int64)]  #20
z[, sum(int64, na.rm=T)] #20
```

And in non-`data.table` format

```
sum(z$int64)
sum(z$int64, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But when including the `by` statement, it gets fishy:

```
    z[, sum(int64, na.rm=FALSE), by=group] #only the negative value
    #group  V1
    #A     -10

    z[, sum(int64, na.rm=TRUE), by=group] #excluding the negative value
    #group  V1
    #A      30

    z[, sum(as.numeric(int64)), by=group] #expected answer
    #group  V1
    #A      20
```

This is worrying to me as on the surface level there is no reason to believe anything is wrong with the numbers in `z$int64` and I only noticed as there were very few rows.

Comment: Try by specifying it as `.SDcols` i.e. `z[, sum(.SD[[1]]), by = group, .SDcols = "int64"]`

Comment: Seems to work for me if you call the method explicitly i.e. `z[, sum.integer64(int64), by=group]`. Not sure why it isn't calling the right method otherwise.

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Comment: @RyanD It's this one, right? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1647 (If so, could comment there that this answer needs updating after it's fixed or thumbs-up the OP)

Comment: @Frank Looks like the same issue there, though the OP came to the different, and I think incorrect, conclusion that the last row is excluded. By adding some rows to my sample, it seems like with `na.rm=FALSE` returns only the *last, negative* row, while `na.rm=TRUE` excludes all the negative rows. I will chime in on that thread.

Comment: Actually, further investigation shows me that `na.rm=FALSE` returns the negative value nearest to 0 by group as the sum.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been corrected, see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1647

```
z[, sum(int64, na.rm=FALSE), by=group]
#    group    V1
#   <char> <i64>
#1:      A    20

z[, sum(int64, na.rm=TRUE), by=group]
#    group    V1
#   <char> <i64>
#1:      A    20

z[, sum(as.numeric(int64)), by=group]
#    group    V1
#   <char> <num>
#1:      A    20
```