# data.table subsetting with J(): odd behavior

Tags: r, data.table

I have two related questions:

1. I'm trying to select rows matching an integer N from a data frame keyed by a single integer64 field, "person_id".  If I use subset(data, person_id == N), everything works fine but is slow.  If I use data[J(N)], I get a single row where person_id column is populated correctly but every other column is set to NA.  I expect 36 rows instead (with non-NA values).
2. I'd like to use the syntax of data[J(v)], where v is a variable set to the value of N.  That takes forever and fails to subset - it returns the original matrix.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example!

Comment: Incredibly, no!  A small example on artificial data works fine, whereas my specific data frame may not be shared in any form for legal reasons.  I'll take educated guesses for answers.

Comment: I can create a very simple reproducible example... (please try harder) - a single data.table with an bit::integer64 column as the key (plus a few other columns). It only needs to be 2 rows.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614846/data-table-is-not-handling-integer64-in-by-statement and https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=2552&group_id=240 -- integer64 isn't implemented for keys yet.

Comment: Thanks!  You are right, I should have tried integer64 as the key.  Ok, I can re-map the keys....