# how to filter data which integer64 class in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table, kaggle

I have a 20GB transaction data set from kaggle (http://www.kaggle.com/c/acquire-valued-shoppers-challenge/data).

row are over 300 million and variables are 11.

It is too heavy to handle with R. So I want to filter data.

[image]

id class is interger64.

Unique id has 311541 and I want sample 20000.

I'm using data.table But there is an error like the picture.

Is there a way to sample id?

Comment: May be you can try by converting to `character` class.  Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614846/data-table-is-not-handling-integer64-in-by-statement

Comment: thanks! converting to character works well.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, `integer64` are just `double`s masked as `integer`. Maybe the best way to obtain your subset without making any copy is to use the `setattr` function in `data.table`. Try this:

```
#remove the integer64 class
setattr(transaction$id,"class",NULL)
custom_sample<-sample(unique(transaction$id),20000)
sample_transac<-transaction[id %in% custom_sample,]
#give the integer64 class back
setattr(sample_transac$id,"class","integer64")
```

Comment: it may be working. but my computer isn't working.
there is an allocated size error.
thank you for answering.